# Two students, one after another without replacement, were chosen randomly from the above sample of $600$ students. What is the probability

Tags: probability, combinations, conditional-probability

[image]

I am sorry I don't know how to create in here so I have attached the picture of it, since this table contains the Data of the problem. So I have been asked to answer the following two questions.

$a)$Two students, one after another without replacement, were chosen randomly
from the above sample of $600$ students. What is the probability that at least one of them
have exceptional academic performance or both are from junior year of study?

$b)$Two students, one after another without replacement, were chosen randomly
from the above sample of $600$ students. Given that at least one chosen student has exceptional academic performance, what is the probability that both chosen students are positive
towards online lessons? Give your answer correct to $4$ decimal places.

**MY WORKING**

$a)$Now the cardinality of sample is given by: $|S|=\frac{600!}{598!*2!}=179700$

From table $|A|=85+45=130$

$|B|=85+290=375$

$|A\cap B|=85$

So: $P(AUB)$=$P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)=0.0023$

$b)$Let $C$ be event that at least once chosen student has exceptional performance and $D$ be event that both chosen students have positive perception toward online classes then:

$|C|=85+45=130$

$|D|=64+29=93$

So $P(D/C)=\frac{P(C\cap D)}{P(C)}$

Now I don't know if I done both parts correctly. Kindly guide me and help me if I am making a mistake

Comment: No - it is not correct, because you have not considered the two students in the numerator and your first probability is much too low.  For example, you could say  $|A| = 130 \times 129 + 130 \times 470 + 470 \times 130$, though taking them in order like this makes $|S|=600 \times 599$

Comment: For part b, you have a similar issue, and you have not calculated $P(C \cap D)$

Comment: I will calculate $P(C\ cap D)$  but I need to be sure that the cardinality of each is found correctly. If not kindly help in in doing so, where have I gone wrong

Comment: If you would like to know how to create tables on this site, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support